# Laravel 5 returns blank page for a method which does not exist

Tags: php, controller, http-status-code-404, laravel-5, restful-url

I created a RESTful controller with *artisan make:controller* and i am using resource method at my routes.php, here is my routes.php:

```
Route::resource('page', 'PageController');
```

I don't have any edit method at my controller (i removed it) so if i hit this URI:

```
http://laravel.dev/page/{id}/edit
```

Laravel should return a 404 page but instance it returns a blank page.

how can i make it return 404 response for a method which does not exist?

Comment: Blank page usually means there's an error somewhere. Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: yes it's on, seems it's looking for edit method and it does nothing when method can't be find. if i add the edit method to controller it's works like a charm :)

Comment: A missing method is not a 404 page, it's a php error

Comment: Yeah, but not when we assuming it as a page, lets say i change the uri to someting like this: http://laravel.dev/page/id/another_method_does_not_exist . it's returns 404 page. but in restful controllers it's assume the edit method exist, even it does not! and it's returns nothing, because there is nothing to return.

Comment: It should throw a MethodNotFoundException, which is a blank page if error reporting is not set

Comment: something like: http://laravel.dev/page/1/bla returns NotFoundHttpException but http://laravel.dev/page/1/edit returns blank page...

Comment: i should mention to it, i removed edit method because i handle the edit process from an other controller, i can use something like abort(404) at all my controllers edit method but it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with the permission of storage directory but I'm wondering why it's just happened at this controller? i had no problem with getting errors from other part of the application.

anyway first i changed the permission of the storage directory:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

then i got the **MethodNotFoundException**, so i add the **only** to the third part of resource method to customize my routes and every thing is fine:

```
Route::resource('page', 'PageController', ['only' => ['index', 'show'] ]);
```

now its throw **NotFoundHttpException**.